# Printing Date Objects to Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, console

I've been doing some work with date objects today and have noticed an unusual behavior that I can't explain.

Imagine this piece of code:

```
var Today = new Date();
var FutureDate = Today.addDays(60);

console.log("Today: " + Today);
console.log("Future: " + FutureDate);

console.log(Today);
console.log(FutureDate);

if(Today == null || Today === null)
{
    console.log("Null!");
}
else if(Today === undefined || Today == undefined)
{
    console.log("Undefined!");
}
else
{
    console.log("Assigned and defined!");
}
```

With the supplementary method:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date;
}
```

This causes the following output:

```
Today: Fri May 24 2019...
Future: Tue Jul 23 2019...
//blank
//blank
Assigned and defined!
```

Why is the date printed when appended in the console and not otherwise? I can see that it's not null, nor undefined. But I'm just confused as to how in some cases `Date.ToString` seems to decide not to work.

EDIT.

By adding toString() to the second console calls  I have managed to get them to print. I can only infer that the toString() method is called when string are concatenated: `"Today: " + Today`, and not when called as a date object.

Why is this the case? I was under the impression that any objects passed as a parameter to a console.log method would be inherently "stringed".

Comment: Have you extendend the Date object?

Comment: can't reproduce. Also `Date` has no `addDays()` method

Comment: @Thomas apologies, didn't think it necessary to the question. The example could have been reproduced with the FutureDate functionality omitted. I've added it, though should have thought about it further, you are correct.